# Why SimpleDateFormat HH works differently from hh

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-parsing

```
    final String sourceDate = "05.12.2014 12:17";
    final String testDate = "05.12.2014 13:17";
    final SimpleDateFormat originalSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm");
    final SimpleDateFormat testSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");

    System.out.println(originalSDF.parse(sourceDate).toString());
    System.out.println(testSDF.parse(sourceDate).toString());
    System.out.println("=====================");
    System.out.println(originalSDF.parse(testDate).toString());
    System.out.println(testSDF.parse(testDate).toString());
```

The output will is:

```
Fri Dec 05 00:17:00 GMT 2014
Fri Dec 05 12:17:00 GMT 2014
=====================
Fri Dec 05 13:17:00 GMT 2014
Fri Dec 05 13:17:00 GMT 2014
```

Why with all time this formats works same, but with 12:* it works different, `hh:mm` parse as `12h` format and `HH:mm` parse as `24h` format?

[prooflink](http://ideone.com/h2BXrD)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date Difference in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675980/date-difference-in-java), see the accepted answer

Comment: The [UNICODE standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) states that "HH" is for a 24-hour notation while "hh" is for a 12-hour notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `originalSDF.setLenient(false)` then parsing `"05.12.2014 13:17"` will throw an exception... basically in lenient mode, `hh` is treated as `HH` (i.e. as a 24-hour value) *when the value is greater than 12* (and possibly when it's 0).

Personally I think that defaulting to lenient mode is a bad idea, but that's a different matter... basically your format *should* always be appropriate for your data. If you're going to get a value of 13:17, you should be using HH:mm.

Comment: I'm now using `HH:mm` format, of course, but i want to understand, why it works so. Now I know, thank you.